# Cat the contents of a .txt file to .bash_profile

Tags: linux, macos, bash, alias, profile

I am setting up a .txt file on my dropbox which will auto-sync between my laptop and desktop. This .txt file contains all of contents of a .bash_profile that I want to keep in sync between these computers, including an alias that currently looks like this:

## Profile configuration

alias bprofud="cat ~/Dropbox/profile.txt > ~/.bash_profle"

(where "bprofud" == a short name for bash profile update)

The idea here is that in order to keep any changes to my bash profile on either computer, I will simply have to edit the text file in my dropbox and then run "bprofud" on each machine.

This doesn't work though. And I am not sure why. It simply writes a new .bash_profile each time instead of overwriting the previous one.

I am running the latest version of MacOSX.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: MIght it be easier to link the file instead of running a command to rewrite it? 

`ln -s ~/Dropbox/profile.txt ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by “it simply writes a new .bash_profile each time instead of overwriting the previous one” but wouldn't it be easier to *source* the shared file into your `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is a simple typo failure ;)

```
alias bprofud="cat ~/Dropbox/profile.txt > ~/.bash_profle"
```

should be

```
alias bprofud="cat ~/Dropbox/profile.txt > ~/.bash_profile"
```

you simply missed the "i"

Comment: Good catch, but now I have to vote for closing the question. ;-)

Comment: I realy thinked about your problem and need time to see it ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could simple have your profile source that dropbox file:

```
[[ -r ~/Dropbox/profile.txt ]] && . ~/Dropbox/profile.txt
```